# What is the correct way to start a MassTransit bus when using the CreateRequestClient method?

Tags: masstransit

I'm using the following code to send a request/response message between two different processes.

This is the process that "sends" the request:

```cs
// configure host
var hostUri = new Uri(configuration["RabbitMQ:Host"]);
services.AddSingleton(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    var host = cfg.Host(hostUri, h =>
    {
        h.Username(configuration["RabbitMQ:Username"]);
        h.Password(configuration["RabbitMQ:Password"]);
    });
}));

// add request client
services.AddScoped(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBus>().CreateRequestClient<QueryUserInRole, QueryUserInRoleResult>(new Uri(hostUri, "focus-authorization"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));

// add dependencies 
services.AddSingleton<IPublishEndpoint>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());
services.AddSingleton<ISendEndpointProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());
services.AddSingleton<IBus>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());

// add the service class so that the runtime can automatically handle the start and stop of our bus 
services.AddSingleton<Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService, BusService>();
```

Here's the implementation of the `BusService`:

```cs
public class BusService : Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService
{
private readonly IBusControl _busControl;

public BusService(IBusControl busControl)
{
    _busControl = busControl;
}

public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return _busControl.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
}

public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return _busControl.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
}
}
```

The problem is that when the `CreateRequestClient` code runs, the bus has not started up yet. Thus the response is never returned from the consumer.

If I replace the host configuration with the following code, I get the desired behavior:

```cs
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    var host = cfg.Host(hostUri, h =>
    {
        h.Username(configuration["RabbitMQ:Username"]);
         h.Password(configuration["RabbitMQ:Password"]);
    });
});
bus.Start();
services.AddSingleton(bus);
```

For some reason, the `BusService(IHostedService)` executes AFTER the `AddScoped` delegates.

My question is: what is the correct way to start up the bus before using the `CreateRequestClient` method? Or is the latter approach to starting up the bus sufficient?

Comment: It shouldn't resolve the scoped type unless you have something that is instantiated at startup using it, which you should only have inside of a controller method (which won't be called until the hosted service is started).

Comment: Chris is completely right, something tries to get a reference to the request client before the service startup cycle is complete. Normally, this should never happen and if it happens, it is definitely not in the code that you posted in the question.

Comment: You guys are correct. The culprit was a custom AuthorizationHandler that was requesting the RequestClient before the bus has started. I'm just not sure why the AuthorizationHandler was resolved during the startup cycle (it should've been resolved by the authorization policies upon controller method execution). Anyway, I've modified my code to explicitly start the bus before declaring the RequestClients. It's working like a charm now!